# How to adjust values in Xcode to depend on device played (iPhone vs. iPad)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently making a classic snake game app.

The app fits and works on all iPhones however when I test on any iPad the lettering is off the screen and so is the game screen.

Is there anyway to adjust the proportion or have it depend on what device you are using?

I was unable to find much help online when looking for this question. (first image is an iPhone 7, and the second is an iPad Air 2.

[image: iPhone 7]

[image: iPad Air 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Adaptive User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/). You should be able to have different layouts for different device sizes using a single storyboard.

You can also change values programatically in your code according to the screen size.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Could not find that!